# strtok() not regarding the new token value on subsequent calls

Tags: c, strtok

I've encountered this rather silly problem using strtok() in C. The routine in the `main` does not appear to be attending to my changed token, while the same works in the `sub_routine` where the only thing that I've done differently is keeping the token character in `static`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sub_routine()
{
  char str[80] = "This is { some important } website";
  char *val = NULL;
  val = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*255);
  strncpy(val, str, sizeof(str));
  static char s = '{';
  char *token;

  /* get the first token */
  token = strtok(val, &s);

  /* walk through other tokens */
  while( token != NULL ) 
  {
    printf( " %s\n", token );
    s= '}';
    token = strtok(NULL, &s);
  }
}

int main()
{
  char symbol='{';
  char *string = NULL;
  char *match = NULL;
  char ref[255]="Do something here {Do it now}. What now?";

  string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 255);
  strncpy(string, ref, sizeof(ref));

  match = strtok(string, &symbol);
  printf("\n%s", match);
  printf("\n%s", string);
  if(string!= NULL)
  {
    symbol = '}';
    match= strtok(NULL, &symbol);
    printf("\n%s\n", match);
  }
  sub_routine();
}
```

Could someone please shed some light on it?

Comment: Why are you using `strtok`? It's one of the worst functions in the c standard library.

Comment: The separators must be given as a null-terminated string. You pass a pointer to a single char, which most liklely isn't null-terminated. Make `s` an array: `char s[2] = "{";`. (The `static` variable may be padded with zero bytes, which could explain your behaviour.)

Comment: @CodesInChaos What alteratives do you suggest (except for its reentrant version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prototype**

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

**str**

C string to truncate.
Notice that this string is modified by being broken into smaller strings (tokens).
Alternativelly, a null pointer may be specified, in which case the function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.

**delimiters**

C string containing the delimiter characters.
These can be different from one call to another.

Change your code as below:

`char symbol="{"`;

It probably works in subroutine because of the s variable is static and is put into RAM where a, after it, is placed a 0x00. This means that could work beacause of lucky...

Comment: Yep, that's probably the cause of the error, but it should be `char *` or maybe even `const char *`.

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` requires a *string* as its second argument.  Here, you are using a pointer to a character, which is 1/2 correct.  However, it is **not** *NULL-terminated* (it does not end with a `(char)0`).  Redefine

```
static char s = '{';
```

and

```
char symbol = '{';
```

to

```
static char *s = "{";
```

and

```
char *symbol = "{";
```

and replace all occurrences of `&s` and `&symbol` in `strtok()` calls with `s` and `symbol`, respectively.